# Where will EU money go?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit

There is no doubt that money from the UK goes to the EU regardless of how much it receives in return. Now that the UK will leave the EU, what will [the money that the UK regularly gives to the EU](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/imageserver/image/methode%2Ftimes%2Fprod%2Fweb%2Fbin%2F15a02d52-c463-11e7-9914-a38dcc178fcd.jpg) be spent on? I was thinking it would go to the NHS due to below photo but that was propaganda, so what is the reality?

Comment: If you don't spend your money to buy that beer, how can you tell you are going to spend it on shoes, gas, or clothing? Even if you had written down budgets before and after, what if several items had budgetary changes? I think the question as asked is impossible to answer.

Comment: The EU currently provides a bunch of services for us (e.g. European Medicines Agency) so replacing those with our own versions at vast expense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of it will likely go to paying the Brexit divorce bill to honor existing obligations, which is expected to be in the range of £[35-39 billion](http://www.businessinsider.com/uk-government-will-pay-a-thirty-nine-billion-brexit-divorce-bill-2017-12). In comparison, the amount that the UK currently sends to the EU per year is approximately £9 [billion](https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/governmentpublicsectorandtaxes/publicsectorfinance/articles/theukcontributiontotheeubudget/2017-10-31). This doesn't include some EU investment in the UK private sector, nor does it consider economic benefits to consumers of lower prices. Any other money returned will likely just go into the UK general fund--there's no reason to think it will be specifically allocated to one source.

Answer (score 4):

Besides all the technicalities regarding the way budgets work or the “divorce bill”, there is a more fundamental reason why you cannot count how much money the UK currently pays into the EU budget and assume this money will be available for any other purpose: Brexit is likely to have huge effects on the economy.

If, as experts warn, growth is depressed (even without a full blown recession), government revenue will be lower and there might very well be nothing left after paying for all current expenses. In the unlikely event that Brexit ushers a new era of prosperity, revenue would increase, some spending would decrease and the government would have an even larger budget surplus to fund additional spending or tax cuts. Either way, looking at the current net contribution to the EU budget tells you very little about the budget outlook in the next few years.